# 1 outlet connects 2 UILabel？

Tags: xcode, label, uilabel, connect, iboutlet

Is it possible to connect 1 outlet from file's owner to 2 `UILabels` from the same view?

I try to do that, but every time I connect the outlet to the other label, it automatic disconnect from outlet to the old label?

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to add new feature to iOS? (just kidding) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. When you add such outlet you say: "I want reference to the object of class UILabel be saved in that variable." So you can save two different values in one variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `IBOutletCollection` instead of an `IBOutlet`. Otherwise, what you are asking for does not make any sense. What are you trying to acheive?